# Creating a context-sensitive grammar (CSG) for the language L = {anbna2n: n ≥ 1}

Tags: context-free, context-sensitive

Need a grammar that can create this language, I am having issues getting a language to work and was looking for help.

Comment: Hello there , are the $n$s and the $2n$ supposed to be exponents?
As in $L = \{a^nb^na^{2n} : n \geq 1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the simplest, but here's a grammar for $L = \{a^nb^na^{2n} : n \geq 1\}$.
Let $G = (\{S, A, B\}, \{a, b\}, P, S)$ where $P$ contains exactly

$$S \to aAbaa$$
$$A \to aAbBB | \varepsilon$$
$$Bb \to bB$$
$$Ba \to aa$$

then $L(G) = L$.